# ¿Como pruebo modelos en laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

Hola hice varios modelos.
Los estoy probando haciendo una consulta a base de datos.
Pero si estos tienen un error me lo mandan directamente. Quiera atrapar este error y manejar lo de una forma distinta.

> El modelo si existe y siempre lo mando a llamar correctamente. Lo que deseo saber es como capturar el error cuando la tabla o la llave primaria no existen.  Este error te lo regresa como tal laravel. Y lo que busco es capturar este mismo error en el controlador donde estoy utilizando el modelo.

```
try {
    $Modelo::all();
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
     print_r($th);
    return false;
}
```

Pero no logro capturar el error antes de que lo dispare. 
Yo quisiera mostrar algo como "Por el momento tenemos un problema".

Si alguien sabe manejar los errores de alguna forma me puede decir por favor.

Saludos.

Comment: quieres mostrar un mensaje de error en que escenario?, ¿cuando no encuentra un valor en la tabla?

Comment: De echo lo busco capturar en el controlador para ejecutar un proceso en el cual cree la tabla en esa base de datos. (Es totalmente seguro dado que este sistema esta en una red privada)

Comment: si, a lo que voy es que no se entiende en tu pregunta el error que deseas capturar, es decir una consulta a la base de datos, la existencia del modelo, no termino de comprender

Comment: A okey perdón. La existencia de la tabla en la base de datos. Disculpa estoy usando modelos dinámicos así que los modelos siempre existen, donde pueden fallar es que no encuentren la tabla en la conexión que utilizan.

Answer (score 1):

Si queres hacer una respuesta http con un mensaje genérico para cualquier error que suceda dentro del try, puedes loguear el error para luego debuguear y retornar la respuesta genérica al usuario.
Para capturar la exepción de que la tabla no exista puedes usar [QueryException](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.html)

Por ejemplo:

```
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException  $exception) {
            Log::error($exception);
            return response()->json([ 'message' => 'Por el momento tenemos un problema' ], 500);
}
```

Comment: Hola ya intente esto. Pero no me funciona laravel sigue lanzando el error y cortando la ejecución.

Comment: Ah, ok, entiendo. ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta la versión de Laravel y de PHP que usas? El trazo de la excepción también podría ser útil.

Comment: Hola disculpa si funciono, El error se producia mas adelante dado que no creaba la tabla. Y este mismo modelo intentaba leer en dicha tabla.

Comment: En si lo que hice fue hacer un sistema que respalda bases de datos copiando las tablas mediante modelos, Estas tablas se actualizan mucho de un día a otro. Por lo que Hacer un dump no me funcionaba bien.

Es mejor solo actualizar las partes que se modifican de dichas tablas. Esto antes lo hacia manualmente, con esto que hice este proceso quedo automatizado.

Comment: Ah, genial. que bueno que lo encontraste. Suena interesante.